# Best practice on forwarding traffic to VMs inside ESXI based on domain name requested?

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-esxi, domain-name

Lets say I have a server with two ip addresses. There are 100 VMs on this server each that hosts a website whose domain names use one of the two IPs in their A records.

What's the best way to route a request coming into ESXI to the appropriate VM depending on which domain name the end user visited?

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with the machines being VMs or them running on vSphere, ESXi's vSwitch is just that, a switch, a layer-2 switch that doesn't even care that the packets it's sending are even IP packets.

Comment: I don't think VMware has anything to do with this. It sounds like you're looking for a _load balancer_.

Answer (score 0):

I'd either use a Brocade or Stingray Traffic Manager. Those enterprise level traffic managers that can do just that. We do use it to do exactly that (well not for websites but still HTTP traffic). You can control it via an API, and it's very robust. The downside would be the pricing. It easily gets into five figures per year if you want a lot of bandwidth and/or a lot of servers.

If you want to go opensource, I'd have a look at `haproxy`. I don't have that much of an experience with that though.